# Subtracting values of two maps whenever there is a key match?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, data-structures, hashmap

I'll explain the logic: I am reading a XML file which contain many request and responses in soap format then I'm storing the request and response in two Hash map. In first Hash map I'm storing transaction Id(unique) as key and values as request time,til-name. In second hash map I'm storing transaction Id(unique) as key and values as response time. In both hash map the keys are same but values are different, by using for loop iterating two loops and I need to get the time difference between response time and request time
eg:request time:2020-01-30T11:07:08.351Z and response time:2020-01-30T11:07:10.152Z

```
public class MapTimeDiff {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

File file =new File("C:\\Users\\gsanaulla\\Documents\\My Received Files\\ecarewsframework.xml");
        Scanner in = null;
        String tilname = null;
        String transactionId = null;
        String requesttime = null;
        String responsetime = null;
        Date dateOne = null;
        Date dateTwo = null;
        double timeDiff;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Map<String,ArrayList<String>> request=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(); 
          ArrayList<String> req=new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String,ArrayList<String>> response=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(); 
        ArrayList<String> res=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while(in.hasNext())
                {
                String line=in.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("</S:Envelope>")) {
                    System.out.println(line);

                    tilname=line.split("StartRecord><")[1].split("><")[0].split(":")[1];
                    System.out.println("tilname :: "+tilname);
                    transactionId = line.split("transactionId>")[1].split("<")[0];
                    System.out.println("transactio id :: "+transactionId);
                    requesttime=line.split("sourceTimestamp>")[1].split("<")[0];
                    System.out.println("request time is :: "+requesttime);
                    dateOne = df.parse(requesttime);

                }
                req.add(tilname);
                req.add(dateOne.toString());
                System.out.println("req is==== " +req);
                request.put(transactionId,req);
                System.out.println("request is==== " +request.get(transactionId));
                    if(line.contains("</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>")) {
                        //System.out.println(line);

                          if(line.contains("transactionId")) 
                          { 
                              responsetime=line.split("sourceTimestamp>")[1].split("<")[0];
                              transactionId = line.split("transactionId>")[1].split("<")[0];
                              System.out.println("responsetime :: "+responsetime); 
                              System.out.println("transaction id "+transactionId);
                              dateTwo = df.parse(responsetime);

                          }
                          res.add(dateTwo.toString());
                          System.out.println("res is===== "+res);
                          response.put(transactionId,res);
                          System.out.println("response is===== "+response.get(transactionId));
                        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : request.entrySet()) {
                              for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry1 : response.entrySet()) {
                             System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                                         ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
                              System.out.println("Key = " + entry1.getKey() + 
                                         ", Value = " + entry1.getValue());
                                  if(request.keySet().equals(response.keySet())) {
                                      timeDiff = (dateTwo.getTime() - dateOne.getTime());
                                  }
                          }
                          } 
}
      }             
        }

           catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }   

    }

}
```

Comment: i havent pasted the entire code but ill explain the logic

Comment: i haven't pasted the entire code but ill explain the logic:i am reading a XML file which contain many request and responses then i m storing the request and response in two Hash map. In first Hash map i m storing transaction Id(unique) as key and values as request time,til-name. In second hash map i m storing transaction Id(unique) as key and values as response time.in both hash map the keys are same but values are different,by using for loop iterating two loops and i need to get the time difference between response time and request time

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should add the explanation in the question and not as comments to be more readable!

Comment: @Stefan :i need to find the difference between response and request time but requesttime is a value in a hashmap and response time is a value in other hashmap

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but maybe you can do something similiar like the following:

```
Map<String, List<String>> requests = Map.of("1", List.of("10,13,12"), "2", List.of("8,7,9"), "3", List.of("11"));
Map<String, List<String>> responses = Map.of("1", List.of("9,10,14"), "2", List.of("8,9,6,12"));

for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> requestEntry : requests.entrySet()) {
    String transactionId = requestEntry.getKey();
    if(responses.containsKey(transactionId)) {
        System.out.println("Transaction Id: " + transactionId);
        for(int i = 0; i < min(requestEntry.getValue().size(), responses.get(transactionId).size()); i++) {
            List<String> requestTimes = asList(requestEntry.getValue().get(i).split(","));
            List<String> responseTimes = asList(responses.get(transactionId).get(i).split(","));
            for(int j = 0; j < min(requestTimes.size(), responseTimes.size()); j++) {
                int requestTime = parseInt(requestTimes.get(j));
                int responseTime = parseInt(responseTimes.get(j));
                System.out.println("Difference: " + abs(requestTime - responseTime));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are no responses for transactionId 3 so this will be ignored.
If elements in the list for a key differ in size (transactionId 2) the surplus elements will also be ignored.

```
Transaction Id: 1
Difference: 1
Difference: 3
Difference: 2
Transaction Id: 2
Difference: 0
Difference: 2
Difference: 3
```

Comment: asList() and parseInt(),i dont have this methods in my code.i have pasted the entire code ,can u please check it

Comment: Use ```Arrays.asList()``` and ```Integer.parseInt()```